# "I had a bit of a thirst on." --- Does this have the same meaning as "I am thirsty"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**"I had a bit of a thirst on."** [ITV-Good morning Britain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yywXkov1E0) (see:4:22-4:25)

Is this simply another way of saying **"I'm thirsty."**?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20bit%20of%20a%2Fan It's also in the Cambridge Dictionary. + to have something [going] on

Comment: It's another way of saying 'I **was** thirsty'.

Comment: It means I was kind of or a little thirsty. However, the Brits understate things often so as not to seem impolite. So where they say a bit of as here, they mean just the regular statement: He was a bit of a bore. could mean: he was real bore.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, Thanks for the comment. Can it also be used for hunger, too? For instance, "I had a bit of a hunger on"?

Comment: No, that sounds pretty awful. You can get by with it with thirsty, though. I was a bit hungry. =ok. Your question contains a very colloquial use of thirst.

Comment: My guess is that almost all instances of someone having ***a bit of a thirst** [**on**]* will be effectively ***metaphoric*** - the subject *wants to drink **alcohol***. Unqualified ***I'm thirsty*** rarely has that implication.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks. That is why I ask about such colloquial usages here on a forum where native english speakers answer, because dictionaries -despite give you the meaning of a phrase- won't tell you that usage is only for a particular a word, as in the case of "thirst". You see, you can use this structure for "thirst" but not for "hunger". And it is impossible for us non-native speakers to know this unless we get it verified by native speakers.

Comment: Yes, but you asked about thirst. And I don't think it's about alcohol but I don't have the patience to look at all the videos. I answered a previous question from you where I did and you chose the other answer when I went to some deal of trouble to answer it.

Comment: @Lambie, Ahhhh Yes, you are right. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The guy went to a funeral. And there are euphemisms for wanting a drink. I guess this might fit that bill.

Comment: It is a very colloquial way of expressing oneself, and, while it does mean "I was thirsty", I think it is unlikely to be a natural way for an English Learner to say "I wanted a (alcoholic) drink".  So avoid this expression if you are not sure. . . There are quite a few explanations in the comments now, so @Yunus perhaps you could summarise in an answer?

Comment: @JamesK, yes I now understood it completely. Thanks to everyone who commented. However, I didn't quite understand your last sentence. Do you mean I should answer my own question, based on the above comments?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  If you understand it now, you can write an answer.

Comment: I just checked all 10 matches on the first page from Google Books for [*got a bit of a thirst on*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+a+bit+of+a+thirst+on%22). Nine definitely related to drinking alcohol - just *one* was indeterminate (but probably cola or juice).

Comment: I just listened to a few seconds of the video link. It's not really a good example of the idiomatic usage. It's obvious the guy's talking about wanting alcohol, not water. But the only likely explanation (assuming he's not an alkie, which seems unlikely) is that he's had to sit through some long ceremony - which was *in reality*, tediously boring (even though in the context of talking about it afterwards, he seems obligated to seem enthusiastic). So boring that he's just desperate to get sloshed as soon as the formalities are over.

Comment: I think we should stop telling learners what to use and not to use. Advanced learners are not beginners. And Yunus is advanced. There are other ways to say things such as people generally don't say this OR this is a one-off usage OR this works but only in conversation. etc.etc.etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's past tense, so more like "I WAS thirsty." But yes, essentially the same thing. "A bit of a thirst" means just a little thirsty. You weren't on the brink of dying of dehydration.

It's informal speech, and while I've heard people say it, I haven't heard it said often. Know what it means but I wouldn't add it to your own speech.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard a speaker of American English use the phrase "I had a bit of a thirst on", but I do recall hearing it on TV shows set in the Australian outback.  In context, it was as FumbleFingers remarked -- the guy wanted a beer.